# How to reconnect network without opening gnome-control-center

Tags: networking, gnome-control-center

I am using ubuntu 20.04, and my problem is that the network connection sometimes terminate. I want to reconnect to the same network, but when I click the wifi icon at the header bar and choose "Select Network", it only permit me to change to another network, otherwise the button "connect" is gray. So I have to open `gnome-control-center` to reconnect the network, but `gnome-control-center` is really slow to start, it takes 3+ seconds to open. So I wonder how I can simply reconnect to the present wifi without opening it.

My current wifi connection is `WPA2` and require both a username and a password, which has already be save in `gnome-control-center`. Reconnecting by either terminal or GUI is ok, but I do not want `sudo`, because entering password is time costly.

By the way, can anyone explain why `gnome-control-center` startup is that slow?

Comment: Rather than playing "beat the clock", why not try and find out what's wrong with your wireless connection?

Comment: List connections `nmcli con`. My WiFi SSID is "Fairfield", so `nmcli con up id Fairfield` works for me. See also https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic

Comment: Diagnose with `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`

Comment: @waltinator Thanks, `nmcli` do what I want.